# Not able to start mongodb server as a long running process

Tags: mongodb

I want to keep MongoDb server running forever or as a background process.
But while doing so it throws me the below error :

**about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections. 
forked process: 12538 
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1.**

Command I have used is :

```
mongod --dbpath="<location of data files>" --fork  --logpath="/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log".
```

Can anyone comment here?

Comment: There must be more information in mongo.log. Can you share it?

Comment: ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo

Comment: But my data/db path exists and I give the same while trying to start mongodb server as a long running process.

Comment: Who owns `/data/db` and which user is starting mongo? Did you check permissions?